# Cannot join a Realm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

A friend of mine owns a Minecraft Realm. I was unable to join, but the weird thing is other friends are playing on that world while I was waiting for it to be fixed.

I am playing on 1.8.9 and the error is: "Failed to login: Authentication servers are currently down for maintenance." Another friend solved the same problem by restarting his computer. I tried this but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you receive any error message when you can't join? Which version of Minecraft are you playing? The fact that your friends are able to join only tells us that the server is probably configured correctly for them, which means the problem is on your end, but you've told us nothing about your setup.

Comment: I am playing on 1.8.9 and the error is :  "Failed to login: Authentication servers are currently down for maintenance .  Another friend solved the same problem by restarting his computer. I tried this but it didnt work.

Comment: Nevermind I solved it

Comment: Then please post your answer so that others who find this question in the future will also know what to do

Comment: use 1.9 and try to get on

Comment: It literraly fixed by itself.